# Getting my vue select to display the correct option

Tags: vue.js

I have a vue page and when the page loads I would like it to select the correct category option based on what my product's category id is, but at the moment that isn't happening and I'm not sure where I've gone wrong.

Here is my code

```
    <template>
        <div class="content-header">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <div class="row mb-2">
                                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                                        <label for="category_select">Select category</label>
                                        <select id="category_select" class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" v-model="categorySelect">
                                            <option v-for="category in categories" :value="category.id" :selected="category.id === product[0]['category_id']">
                                                {{ category.name }}
                                            </option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        export default {
            props: ['product'],
            data(){
                return {
                    categories: [],
                    categorySelect: null
                }
            },
            computed: {

            },
            methods: {
                getCategories(){
                    axios.get('/api/categories/getCategories').then(response => {
                        this.categories = response.data.categories;
                    });
                },

            },
            mounted(){
                this.getCategories();
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve my problem this is what I did.

I changed

```
    data(){
        return {
            categories: [],
            categorySelect: null
        }
    },
```

to

```
    data(){
        return {
            categories: [],
            categorySelect: this.product[0]['category_id'],
        }
    },
```

and I removed `:selected="category.id === product[0]['category_id']"`

Comment: Your v-model is your select :)
and m.b. you need to add it after mount:
mounted(){
                this.getCategories();
                this.categorySelect = this.product[0]['category_id'];
            }